# How can I start being a useful member of this community?

Tags: discussion, help, guidelines

I understand that the rules are very strict, and should be as such, so how can I start off successfully and become a useful member of the community?

The advice of experienced members would be welcome.

**Note**: I do not just need faster ways to get reputation points, I want to be a useful community member.

Comment: In that case learn to search before posting is the best tip to be a useful community member. What other posts on this site already answer your questions? Why haven't you read them? If you have read them why are you still confused?

Comment: I was,but noone explain how to became usefull,most is about reputation.Thanks for comment me.

Comment: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/4642212).

Comment: The best way to contribute to the site is to contribute to it as a *knowledge base*. Like Wikipedia, kinda, but in more bite-sized pieces. Which means post high-quality, interesting and novel questions, and high-quality, authoritative and complete answers. Before you ask for “more expert” guidance on that, though: there are literally hundreds  of posts by experienced users on this Meta and the meta of each site, with links to other resources on the internet, as well as thousands of powerful examples. Asking for personal advice tells us you don’t want to do the research on your own.

Comment: Well, if by "useful" you mean do moderation tasks, the only way is by gaining reputation. Will try looking for better dupe though.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty forward: start suggesting edits, each of them that gets approved increases your reputation with +2. And you get up to 500 chances to do so ... The result is that you'll have a rep increase of over 1K ...

Other options:

- post *good* questions, and/or *good* answers.
- suggest edits for tag excerpts and/or tag descriptions.
- select the "best" answer to any of your questions, and mark that as accepted ... You'll be surprised what happens next to your reputation.
- try to answer questions with an active *bounty*, it may result in your answer being rewarded (part of) the bounty.
- once you earned *sufficient* rep on at least 1 site, you'll get an *association bonus* for any other site you signed up before, or will sign up in the future.

PS: in [revision 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/318733/timeline), created after I answered the original post, you (OPer) removed a crucial part (= "without reputation") that my answer is related to. Therefor that revision invalidates part of my answer. However, according to the rules of any SE site, edits that invalidate existing answers are NOT allowed. So I suggest you (OPer) restore that crucial part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Take the Tour of every site you join, then review at least the on-topic page from its Help Center too.

Then review a number of Q&As from the site including a few like the one you are thinking of asking to see how they fared.

Do a thorough search of the Internet and the site for the exact question you wish to ask.

If you still need to ask your question, do so, and monitor it for as long as you can so that you can address any clarifications that potential answerers and site curators may seek from you.

Ask only one question per question and make what you are asking as clear as possible.

Comment: With my reputation i can give only feedback which i done yet.